# align img and input in jsp

Tags: html, css

I have a page in my mvc application with a `<form:form>`.  At the end of the form I have 2 'buttons'.  One is an image which calls a javascript function and the other is a input which is used to submit control back to the controller.

```
<img alt="back" src="Back.png" class="mousechange" onclick="div_hideshow ('#tab5', '#tab4' )">
<input type="image" id="submit" name="submit" src="tick.jpg" />
```

They are misaligned, the input item being a good 20 odd pixels higher than the img. Could anyone tell me a simple way to align the 2 buttons ?

Comment: Tip : always add width and height for your image, your browser will thank you and load the image faster, and you can adapt your style easily knowing the dimension of your image.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I actually trimmed them off for readability although I did forget initially but the image was not as expected !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles:

```
img, input{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It would be better to assign them classes rather than using these broad element selectors.

Comment: many thanks.  I've done it inline for now and will add classes to tidy when it's good to go (famous last words...)

Comment: Thanks, can you mark it correct if you're satisfied.